# How can i use the wait_for("reaction_add") function only for a specific message? discord.py

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

Like the bot won't read any other reactions of messages but only of a specific message.

will adding `reaction.message == msgg` into this code helps the trick?
(I don't know whether that function even exists and I did test that too but doesn't work for me)

```
reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add")
if user == members.user and str(reaction.emoji) == "✔️":
  await members.user.send("your answer is ✔️")
else:
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

You would check if the `reaction.message.content` is the same as the message you desire.

```py
reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add")
if reaction.message.content == "<desired message>":
    if user == members.user and str(reaction.emoji) == "✔️":
        await members.user.send("your answer is ✔️")
    else:
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on_reaction_add` function for this, and then check if the message the user is reacting to is the desired one.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
      if user.bot:
         return
      my_message_id = 1234567
      if reaction.message.id == my_message_id
         await message.channel.send("Your answer is ✔️")
      else:
         return
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with the `check` parameter of the `wait_for` Function:

```
reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda m: m.id == MESSAGE_ID)

if user == members.user and str(reaction.emoji) == "✔️":
    await members.user.send("your answer is ✔️")

else:
    return
```

(Idk if the `lambda m` and `m.id` works for reactions, you would have to test this out)